# rooted tree with internal vertices with exactly 2 children. Prove with induction that $|V| = 2k +1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, induction, trees

I am struggling to understand graph theory induction questions. I understand the basics of induction as well as graph theory, however, when working on these types of problems I seem to struggle to find a good approach for them. I would like for someone to help solve this problem and walk through their method of working on problems such as this. The question is as follows:

Let $T = (V, E)$ be a rooted tree with the property that every internal vertex has exactly 2 children. If there are $k$ internal vertices, prove by induction that $|V | = 2k + 1$.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform induction on $k$.  The bases $k=0$ and $k=1$ are easy.  Suppose now that $T$ is a rooted tree with $k>1$ internal vertices.

Having at least $k\ge 2$ vertices, the tree has at least one leaf, so let $v$ be a leaf.  Note that $v$ can't be the root, so it has a parent.  If $u$ is a parent of $v$, then $u$ must have another child $w$.  Removing $v$ and $w$ from $T$ yields another rooted tree with $k-1$ internal vertices ($u$ is now no longer an internal vertex).  This new tree must have $2(k-1)+1=2k-1$ vertices by our induction hypothesis.  Therefore, $T$ must have $2k-1+2=2k+1$ vertices (since we are adding $v$ and $w$ back).

Here is another solution.  Let $n$ be the number of vertices.  Then the tree has $n-k$ leaves.  The root has degree $2$.  Each non-root internal vertex has degree $3$ (for it has one edge joining it to its parent, and two edges joining it to its two children), so the degree sum is
$$2+3(k-1)+(n-k)=n+2k-1.$$
But the tree must have $n-1$ edges, so the degree sum should be $2(n-1)$.  That is,
$$n+2k-1=2(n-1)\implies n=2k+1.$$

**Generalisation:**  A rooted tree with $k$ internal vertices in which each internal vertex has exactly $t$ children must have exactly $tk+1$ vertices.  Even more generally if $T$ is a finite rooted tree such that for a non-negative integer $n$ there are $k_n$ vertices with exactly $n$ children, then $T$ has $\sum_{n=0}^\infty nk_n+1$ vertices.